# How to convert MathNumeric value to Integer Java

Tags: java

I am not a java developer. Just have basic understanding.
I am consuming a web service and it is sending one field value that is a  MathNumeric data type.
I assign the value like below and import the MathNumeric from package class

```
import oracle.e1.bssv.jp55cl.MathNumeric;

MathNumeric m = val.getDocVoucher();
```

and on console the value is coming something like below

```
MathNumeric@470e2030
MathNumeric@3fb4f649
MathNumeric@33833882
MathNumeric@200a570f
MathNumeric@16b3fc9e
MathNumeric@e2d56bf
```

I am trying to find out, how can i parse MathNumeric to integer.
I know parse integer function can parse String value. But is there a function that can parse MathNumeric to integer.

Need some help with that I would relish it very much.

Comment: Find out what methods it has, and call them. Don't simply print out the object like you're doing, since it makes no sense to print out this output from the object's `toString()` method. Look up the API and study it.

Comment: Try `m.intValue()` to extract the int from the MathNumeric object

Comment: We don't know what `oracle.e1.bssv.jp55cl.MathNumeric` is. It is likely defined in your web service WSDL file. If you want help with it, you need to provide the definition of `MathNumeric`, e.g. the source for it.

Comment: A deep dive into Google only reveals that the Javadoc is likely not viewable publicly.  So you'll have to find it on your system and answer your own question.

Comment: If you use an IDE, it will help show you the available methods on `MathNumeric`.

Comment: I can't find the Javadoc online, but I've found code examples that seem to suggest that `MathNumeric` has a method called `intValue()`.  It looks like Hovercraft may have found similar examples.  So take Hovercraft's advice and call `intValue()`.

Comment: Exactly as @DawoodibnKareem mentions. I've also seen `new Integer(m.intValue())`, but surely the OP could find this if both Dawood and I found it in seconds in a Google search, no?

Comment: Thanks for the response folks. That's what I also found but I just recently installed Eclipse Photon and intValue() is not showing in intellisense. I guess this function doesnt exist anymore. Thats why I posted this question if there might be another way of going about this.

Answer (score 0):

As per this link: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17984_01/doc.898/e14694/create_publishedbssv.htm

This should work:

```
public void setNumberField(MathNumeric numberField){
   if(numberField!= null)
      this.numberField= new Integer(numberField.intValue());
}
```

Please note numberField is Integer and not int in above example.
If you want int you can just do:

```
int number = numberField.intValue();
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: intValue() is not showing up in intellisense. I just installed Eclipse IDE photon. Is this function obsolete now?